# AWS route53 domain not working with www prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have a domain with AWS with static website hosting option with S3.

Have all my static files under S3 with the bucket name as

> domain.com

Since I need https, I created CloudFront with the following alternate CNAMEs.

> ```
> domain.com 
> www.domain.com
> ```

Have A records for both domain.com & [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com).

```
For domain.com --> CloudFront

For www.domain.com --> route to domain.com
```

Hitting, domain.com works, but [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) gives error that bucketname wwww.domain.com doesn't exist.

I can create one more bucket with [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and copy all the static files. Is this the only approach?

Answer (score 2):

as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-configure-redirect) you just need to configure the redirects from the subdomain bucket. No need t o copy the objects from the root bucket.
quoting from the doc

> After you configure your root domain bucket for website hosting, you can configure your subdomain bucket to redirect all requests to the domain. In this example, all requests for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) are redirected to example.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your own domain name, such as [www.my-custom-domain.com](http://www.my-custom-domain.com) and my-custom-domain.com, instead of the cloudfront.net domain name, you can add an alternate domain name to your distribution,
like [www.my-custom-domain.com](http://www.my-custom-domain.com) and my-custom-domain.com.

1. Choose the ID for the distribution that you want to update.
2. On the General tab, choose Edit.
3. Update the following values:

   **Alternate Domain Names** (CNAMEs) Add your alternate domain names.
   Separate domain names with commas, or type each domain name on a new
   line.
   [image]

In your domain hosted zone in Route 53, select to Create Record Set.
you need to create an A record for IPv4 and  select the Alias option.
In the Alias Target, you will find your CloudFront distribution — select and save. your Alternate Domain Names you configured in CloudFront must match the record set name.

Answer (score 0):

Just going from the guides on Route53 and a quick test, it looks like the bucket name has to match:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started.html

You've probably read these already, I can't find another way. Sorry.